# Why React fails to render changes in array of JSX element when using .map index as a key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Inside this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMaXrr?&editors=0010) there is React application that renders list of ToDo's. **It uses `.map()` `index` parameter as `key` values to render this list.** *And yes - I know that this is the source of this behaviour, so Please don't tell this in answers.*

I've added few items there after initial load and then I see this:

[image]

Then I sort it by date and type something into first item

[image]

Then I click on `Sort by Latest` and get this:

[image]

**Question: Why React fails to render changes in array of JSX element when using .map index as a key in this particular example?**

P.S. Here is the code for convenience:

```
const ToDo = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>{props.id}</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>{props.createdAt.toTimeString()}</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
);

class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const date = new Date();
    const todoCounter = 1;
    this.state = {
      todoCounter: todoCounter,
      list: [
        {
          id: todoCounter,
          createdAt: date,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  sortByEarliest() {
    const sortedList = this.state.list.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.createdAt - b.createdAt;
    });
    this.setState({
      list: [...sortedList],
    });
  }

  sortByLatest() {
    const sortedList = this.state.list.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.createdAt - a.createdAt;
    });
    this.setState({
      list: [...sortedList],
    });
  }

  addToEnd() {
    const date = new Date();
    const nextId = this.state.todoCounter + 1;
    const newList = [
      ...this.state.list,
      {id: nextId, createdAt: date},
    ];
    this.setState({
      list: newList,
      todoCounter: nextId,
    });
  }

  addToStart() {
    const date = new Date();
    const nextId = this.state.todoCounter + 1;
    const newList = [
      {id: nextId, createdAt: date},
      ...this.state.list,
    ];
    this.setState({
      list: newList,
      todoCounter: nextId,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <code>key=index</code>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.addToStart.bind(this)}>
          Add New to Start
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.addToEnd.bind(this)}>
          Add New to End
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.sortByEarliest.bind(this)}>
          Sort by Earliest
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.sortByLatest.bind(this)}>
          Sort by Latest
        </button>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th />
            <th>created at</th>
          </tr>
          {this.state.list.map((todo, index) => (
            <ToDo key={index} {...todo} />
          ))}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ToDoList />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that inputs are not changed at all here and as they are not controlled (so their attributes/text values didn't change), it makes sense as the root element is not changed in context of React reconciliation (it has still same `key`). Then React goes to text nodes that eventually are different and then refreshes (updates DOM) only those changed nodes.

So there are two variants to make this work:

1. Use meaningful `key`, not `index` from `.map()`
2. Add (in our specific case) attributes to `<input />`

In general first approach is better as the `key` property will invalidate the *root* element (in our case whole `ToDo`) and force it to render itself, saving us comparison of nested subtree.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Why React fails to render changes in array of JSX element when using .map index as a key in this particular example?

Don't use the list index as a key. The point of the key is to identify your individual entries from one render to another. When you change the order of the array, react will not know that anything has changed, because the order of the indexes in the todo array is still `0, 1, 2, 3 ...` Instead use the todo.id as key.

React hasn't failed to render the new order. It's doing exactly as expected. You are telling it the order is exactly the same as last render, but that the properties of the individual todo items have changed.

What you want to say is that it's the ordering that has changed. Then you have to pass a meaningful key. Then react will use the same dom elements, but change the order.

This means that you can do something like [react-shuffle](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-shuffle) where a transition effect lets you see how the elements are reordered.

[image]

Comment: I know this, but want to understand why is this so. Please tell if this makes sense: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48989970/2730688 ?

Comment: Check this question. It's not a duplicate of this one, but the answers contain an explanation of how `key` works, and what it's for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not have stable ID's (your indexes change after the filter). See the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

And you have another problem, because you are mutating your list when you sort it:

```
sortByEarliest() {
    const sortedList = this.state.list.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.createdAt - b.createdAt;
    });
    this.setState({
      list: [...sortedList],
    });
  }

  sortByLatest() {
    const sortedList = this.state.list.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.createdAt - a.createdAt;
    });
    this.setState({
      list: [...sortedList],
    });
  }
```

The [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) alter your array. So you could use this solution:

```
  sortByEarliest() {
    const { list } = this.state;
    list.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt);
    this.setState({ list });
  }

  sortByLatest() {
    const { list } = this.state;
    list.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt);
    this.setState({ list });
  }
```

Comment: your answer doesn't answer my question. I know conditions when this will work as they are in the docs link you've provided and that I've read yesterday. My question is - WHY in this specific situation it behaves like this - with `key={index}`. **Secondly** I didn't get part about sort - making this change doesn't make the application work. so the question persists.